# Does Tensorflow TFDetect demo track objects end-to-end?

Tags: android, tensorflow

This question is regarding TFDetect demo which is available as a part of [Tensorflow Android Camera Demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android/). The description says,

> Demonstrates a model based on Scalable Object Detection using Deep
>   Neural Networks to localize and **track** people in the camera preview in
>   real-time.

When I ran the demo, the app was creating boxes around detected objects with a fractional number assigned to each object (I guess the confidence score). My question is, how is tracking being performed here. Is it multiple object tracking (described [here](https://motchallenge.net/)) where there is an id assigned to each track and the tracks are stored in the memory, or is it just detection of objects across multiple frames to see how the object is moving?

Please correct me if I missed out on anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two main things are going on here:

1: detection is being done in a background thread. This takes on the order of 100-1000ms depending on device, so is not sufficient to maintain smooth tracking.

2: tracking is being done in the UI thread. This generally takes < 5ms per frame, and can be done on every frame once the position of objects is known. The tracker implements pyrimidal lucas-kanade optical flow on the median movement of FAST features -- press the volume key and you'll see the individual features being tracked.

The tracker runs on every frame, storing optical flow keypoints at every timestamp. Thus, when a detection comes in, the tracker is able to figure out where it currently is by walking the position forward along the collected keypoints deltas. There is also some non-max suppression being done as well by multiboxtracker.

Once an object is tracked by the tracker, no further input from the detector is required. The tracker will automatically drop the track when the normalized cross-correlation with the original detection drops below a certain threshold, or update the position/appearance when the detector finds a better match with significant overlap.